# Floating and clearing in IE7

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, css-float

Currently I'm trying to implement a HTML 5 site. On one of the pages I I have the following HTML structure

```
<ul class="catList">
  <li class="cat rowStart">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Consetetur sadipscing elitr... Consetetur sadipscing elitr... Consetetur sadipscing elitr...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat rowEnd">
    <h4>Dozer Bags</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum... At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum... At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum... At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat rowStart">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Consetetur sadipscing elitr... Consetetur sadipscing elitr...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua... Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua... Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua... Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua... Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum... Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua... Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua... Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat rowEnd">
    <h4>Dozer Bags</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat rowStart">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Consetetur sadipscing elitr Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua... Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat rowEnd">
    <h4>Dozer Bags</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The accompanying CSS is as follows:

```
.catList {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: sandybrown;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 1000px;
}
.catList li {
    float: left;
    width: 249px;
    margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
    background: orchid;
}
.catList li.rowStart {
    clear: both;
}
```

(the colours are obviously just for demonstration purposes :) )

This layout works fine in IE8, and in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera.  The .rowStart list items get pushed to the next row, and all the following list items have their tops lining up fine with the first one as intended, regardless of whether all teh list items are the same height or not.

Howevern in IE7, the layout breaks quite badly.  The .rowStart list item itself gets cleared as expected, but the following list items don't appear to clear the previous row.

Is this because I'm trying to use HTML5 in IE7 or is there something I'm missing in my CSS?

I'm not worried about IE6 compatibility.

EDIT: Don't know if this is relevant, but I'm basing the HTML on the HTML5 boilerplate, and am using modernizr.js

EDIT 2: Here's the full document structure (ommitting the actual list, as you've seen that already)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" >
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" >
        <meta name="language" content="en" >
        <title>Title goes here</title>
        <link href="/css/html5.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
        <link href="/css/core.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
        <!--[if lte IE 7]> <link href="/css/ie7.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ><![endif]-->     
        <!--[if lt IE 7]> <script type="text/javascript/" src="/css/iepngfix/iepngfix_tilebg.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/modernizr-2.5.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="siteWrap">
            <header>
                <p>Header stuff goes here</p>
                <nav class="topNav">
                    <ul class="headerLinks clearfix">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a>
                        <li><a href="/">link 2</a>
                        <li><a href="/">link 3</a>
                        <li><a href="/">link 4</a>
                        <li><a href="/">link 5</a>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div class="main">
                <nav class="breadcrumbs">
                    <p>You are in:</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li>Breadcrumb 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <p>Catalogue preamble goes here</p>

                <ul class="catList">
                    <!-- ommitted because it's already in the question -->
                </ul>

                <p>Catalogue postamble goes here</p>

            </div>

            <footer>
                <p class="copyright"><small>&copy; Copyright Foo Bar 2012</small></p>
                <nav class="bottomNav">
                    <ul class="footerLinks">
                        <li><a href="#" class="social twitter">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="social facebook">Follow on Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stockists</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT 3: Updated the list item contents to something more likely to cause IE7 to break

Comment: I don't see any HTML5 in your given code?

Comment: @BoltClock The given code is just the list that's causing difficulty.  I didn't want to post an entire HTML document for just the list.  FYI, it's embedded in a section tag which in turn is wrapped in an article tag.

Comment: I created a fiddle, it looks the same everywhere to me. http://jsfiddle.net/RGWy4/

Comment: @BoltClock Added the full markup to the question as an edit

Comment: @AlexMorales I fiddles with your fiddle and found that it would render correctly or otherwise depending on how much content there was in each individual list item (if they all have more or less the same content length it works but if there's a lot of variety in the content length the layout breaks in IE7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: removed old superfluous stuff

Option 1, this css worked:

```
.catList {
overflow: hidden;
background: sandybrown;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
width: 1000px;
overflow:auto;
}
.catList li {
min-height:1px;
float: left;
width: 249px;
margin: 0 1px 0px 0;
background: orchid;
min-height:1px;
}
.catList li.rowStart {
clear: both; 
}

.catList li.spacer{
font-size:1px;
line-height:1px;
text-height:1px;
height:1px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:1000px;
background:#000;
float:none;
clear:both;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="catList">
  <li class="cat rowStart">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Consetetur sadipscing elitr...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat rowEnd">
    <h4>Dozer Bags</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="spacer"></li>
  <li class="cat rowStart">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Consetetur sadipscing elitr...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Bobilicius Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat rowEnd">
    <h4>Dozer Bags</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat rowStart">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="cat rowEnd">
    <h4>Dozer Bags</h4>
    <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Option 2: Nested Lists

CSS:

```
.catList {
    background: sandybrown;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 1000px;
}
.catList li.catRow li {
    float: left;
    width: 249px;
    margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
    background: orchid;
    display:inline-block;
    }

.catList li.catRow {
    float:left;
    width:1000px;
    clear:left;
    min-height:1px;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="catList">
    <li class="catRow">
        <ul>
            <li class="cat">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p class="shortDesc">Consetetur sadipscing elitr...</p>
            </li>
            <li class="cat">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p class="shortDesc">Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...</p>
            </li>
            <li class="cat">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
            </li>
            <li class="cat">
                <h4>Dozer Bags</h4>
                <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="catRow">
        <ul>
            <li class="cat">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p class="shortDesc">Consetetur sadipscing elitr...</p>
            </li>
            <li class="cat">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p class="shortDesc">Sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua...</p>
            </li>
            <li class="cat">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
            </li>
            <li class="cat">
                <h4>Dozer Bags</h4>
                <p class="shortDesc">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum...</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, no joy.  Thanks for the reply though (FYI I'm Windows Virtual PC to run the old versions of IE, I've found the compatibility mode in IE9 isn't very reliable at simulating them)

Comment: ah, hang on, changing content length, the simlutated ie7 does show the problem (maybe edit that in your sample). Looking at options for you now.

Comment: I have added in the spacer li between your rows (only applied to the first row for now), and then applied the css for the spacer

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you're putting in.  However, I'd really prefer to find some kind of solution that doesn't introduce markup that only serves to work around a browser bug.  I did think about going with inline-block, but the designer guy I work with advises against using those, and they seem to introduce unwanted white space between the elements.

Comment: I agree unecessary markup is not ideal, but that is the only way I could het your idea to work in ie7. I recall having a similar problem with ie7 when it was new.

Comment: OK, +1 because it is a solution that would work, but I'm going to hold off accepting for now because I really would rather find a way of resolving this without unnecessary markup.

Comment: I have Added a nested list option as well - more semantiacally correct than the spacer, but also more markup. I think chances of finding a css only version seem slim, as this seems to be a genuine ie7 float bug.

Comment: I suspect if I go with the extra markup approach I'd go with the list of lists approach because, as you say, it's more semantic.  I'll still keep plugging at it though, I'm sure I'm far from the first person to have this issue and there must be solutions out there.