# IE7: float left, but not upwards, please

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, css-float

See  this simple HTML code: http://www.pastie.org/3540274

On modern browsers and even IE8 and IE9 it looks like this:

```
[A1]
[B1][B2]
[C1][C2][C3]
```

However in IE7 mode it displays like:

```
[A1][B2][C2]
[B1][C3]
[C1]
```

DIVs with

```
{ float:left; clear:none }
```

are not only floating to the left, but also upwards. Is there a way to avoid that without or without much extra markup?

Comment: IE7 floating is a pain!

this thread may help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330995/floating-and-clearing-in-ie7/9331118#9331118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an object level spacer between your rows, or a separate container for each row in order for it to work in IE7.

Examples are in this thread:
[Floating and clearing in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330995/floating-and-clearing-in-ie7/9331118#9331118)

this was in a list, but the same would apply to divs.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to go with containers then. I hoped there was a solution without markup. For anyone who's interested, here's the modified working example http://www.pastie.org/3541882

Comment: yeah, unfortunately IE7 does require the additional markup. I have not yet found an effective css only solution, and I have been looking since ie7 was new!